# Discontinuous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Is there a solution to the following equation? If so, what is it?

$$\frac{df}{dt}=
\begin{cases}
-t, & f\geq 0\\
t, & f<0
\end{cases}$$
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $t\geq 0$ instead of $f\geq 0$ ?

Comment: No, I mean f, not t. It would be a lot easier if it were t xD So far I have tried separating variables, which didn't work. I really don't know how to go about this one...

Comment: What about defining $t(f)$ as the (local) inverse of $f$? The ODE is now $dt/df= -1/t$ if $f\ge0$ and $dt/df= 1/t$ oherwise

Comment: Wouldn't that just yield the same as separating the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $f(t)=0$ is impossible for any nonzero $t$. Namely, we would then have $f'(t)=-t$ which is nonzero, so in any neighborhood of $t$ there would be points with negative $f$ (and so $f'$ close to $t$) and points with positive $f$ (and so $f'$ close to $-t$). Since $f'(t)=0$ only at $t=0$, this would contradict Darboux's theorem which guarantees that $f'$ has the intermediate value property.

Suppose $f(1)=a>0$. Then we must have
$$ f(t) = a+\frac12 - \frac12t^2 $$
for $t\in[1,\sqrt{2a+1})$ -- but then $f(\sqrt{2a+1})$ must be $0$ by continuity, which is impossible.

Mutatis mutandis we can see that $f(1)<0$ is also impossible.

So there can be no solution defined on all of $\mathbb R$.